# Getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' error while woring in Kivy

Tags: python, camera, kivy

I am exploring kivy to deploy my ml model. I have wrote the code to access the camera using kivy but I'm getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' error.  Can Anyone help me?

Here is the error:

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.image =Image()
        layout.add_widget(self.image)
        layout.add_widget(MDRaisedButton(
            text="click here",
            pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5},
            size_hint=(None, None)
        ))
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.load_video,1.0/30.0)
        return layout

    def load_video(self,*args):
        ret,frame = self.capture.read()
        #frame load and frame initialize
        self.image_frame = frame
        buffer = cv2.flip(frame,0).tostring()
        texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture.blit_buffer(buffer, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.image.texture = texture
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: aalways put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: show minimal working code with this problem. Without code all this question is only waste of time.

Comment: probably it can't find your camera - so `opencv` gets `None` instead of `frame` and later it tries to do `None.shape`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a resolution anywhere in your code but when I ran into the same error using the example from Kivy documentation, I was able to fix it by changing my resolution from 640 x 480 to self.resolution